# Aliases in subshell / child process

Tags: linux, shell, alias

I set up aliases in /etc/profile.d/alias.sh for each login shell. But if I run script.sh, I can't use that alias. How can I set alias even for subshells or child processes ?

/etc/profile.d/alias.sh

```
alias rmvr='rm -rv';
alias cprv='cp -rv';
alias mvrv='mv -rv';
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Aliases are not inherited.  That's why they are traditionally set in `bashrc` and not `profile`.  Source your `script.sh` from your `.bashrc` or the system-wide one instead.

Comment: By inhereted, you mean that for instance exported variables are inherited and the rest is not ?

Comment: I don't think that .bashrc helps... If you use that alias then in a subshell, it doesn't know it

Comment: bashrc is read for all interactive non-login shells which is why this should work since most shells you start up are interactive non-login shells, and aliases do work in subshells with `()`

Comment: I didn't know about aliasName() invocation, thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, what I meant was in bash, `alias foo='echo foobar'`, enter, `(foo)` outputs `foobar`.

Answer (score 36):

If you want them to be inherited to sub-shells, use functions instead. Those can be exported to the environment (`export -f`), and sub-shells will then have those functions defined.

So, for one of your examples:

```
rmvr() { rm -rv "$@"; }
export -f rmvr
```

If you have a bunch of them, then set for export first:

```
set -a # export the following funcs
rmvr() { rm -rv "$@"; }
cpvr() { cp -rv "$@"; }
mvrv() { mv -rv "$@"; }
set +a # stop exporting
```

Comment: This is super useful and solves my problem.

Answer (score 11):

It is because /etc/profile.d/ is used only by interactive login shell. However, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is used by interactive non-login shell.

As I usually do set some global aliases for system, I have started to create `/etc/bashrc.d` where I can drop a file with some global aliases:

```
    HAVE_BASHRC_D=`cat /etc/bash.bashrc | grep -F '/etc/bashrc.d' | wc -l`

    if [ ! -d /etc/bashrc.d ]; then
            mkdir -p /etc/bashrc.d
    fi
    if [ "$HAVE_BASHRC_D" == "0" ]; then
        echo "Setting up bash aliases"
            (cat <<-'EOF'
                                    if [ -d /etc/bashrc.d ]; then
                                      for i in /etc/bashrc.d/*.sh; do
                                        if [ -r $i ]; then
                                          . $i
                                        fi
                                      done
                                      unset i
                                    fi
                            EOF
            ) >> /etc/bash.bashrc

    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question, I wanted to run bash "command mode" and have aliases available:

`bash -i 'alias'` does nothing.  But I discovered the [-i flag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) which does run the interactive setups, so this: `bash -ci 'alias'` does work.

For your question, appears you can kind of circumvent it by "sourcing" the file, ex:

```
 bash -ci '. script.sh'
```

Then aliases work.  FWIW...

Answer (score -1):

You can use case statement like this:

```bsh
function execute() {
        case $1 in
                ls) $@ --color=auto ;;
              grep) $@ --color=auto ;;
             fgrep) $@ --color=auto ;;
             egrep) $@ --color=auto ;;
                 *) $@ ;;
        esac
}


( execute $@ )
```